# Linked list insertion function issue in C

Tags: c

Basically insertion in the middle works but when I want to insert a value as first one(in beggining) it inserts but also displays an adress I guess(the data sectiion of listhead).

What do I have to modify in order that the listhead will point to new element?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
struct entry {
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

//X position struct u want to target
struct entry *insertentry(struct entry *new_entry, struct entry *x){
    int data;


    printf("Enter a value for your new entry\n");
    scanf("%i",&data);
    new_entry->value=data;
    new_entry->next=x->next;
    x->next=&(*new_entry);
    return new_entry;
};

int main (void)
{
    struct entry n1, n2, n3,*n4,n5;
    struct entry list_head, *list_pointer=&list_head;
    list_head.next=&n1;
    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.value = 300;
    n4=insertentry(&n5,&list_head);
    n3.next = (struct entry *) 0; // Mark list end with null pointer
    while ( list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0 ) {
        printf ("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }
    printf("%i\n",n5.value);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to modify your indentation. Linked lists in c dont work unless the indentation is correct ....

Comment: I suggest you get into the habit of using `NULL` instead of the clumsy `(struct entry *) 0`

Comment: This code doesn't compile, so I'm not sure how you got it to "print an address": http://ideone.com/mvgxef

Comment: x->next=&(*new_entry); should be x->next=new_entry;

Comment: `list_pointer=&list_head.next` --> `*list_pointer=&list_head`

Comment: and set value to `list_head.value`

Comment: Check it made some changes

Comment: BLUEPIXY i don't need actually to give to it a value

Comment: use pointer instead of.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I don't have conio.h so I removed it here. You missed to correctly set the variable to `list_pointer=&n1;`.

This code should do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct entry {
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

//X position struct u want to target
struct entry *insertentry(struct entry *new_entry, struct entry *x){
    int data;


    printf("Enter a value for your new entry\n");
    scanf("%i",&data);
    new_entry->value=data;
    new_entry->next=x->next;
    x->next=&(*new_entry);
    return new_entry;
};

int main (void)
{
    struct entry n1, n2, n3,*n4,n5;
    struct entry list_head, *list_pointer=list_head.next;
    list_head.next=&n1;
    list_pointer=&n1; // That was missing
    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.value = 300;
    n4=insertentry(&n5,&list_head);
    n3.next = (struct entry *) 0; // Mark list end with null pointer
    while ( list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0 ) {
        printf ("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }
    printf("%i\n",n5.value);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, if i want to insert a node before the n1(struct header) means i will create another struct header

Comment: @PandaHru if you want to have a system where you can insert X nodes, you will have to dynamically allocate every node within insertNode(...) or reserve some "static" memory and points towards it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not display an address but the unintialized value of list_head.next

```
int main (void)
{
    struct entry n1, n2, n3,*n4,n5;
    struct entry list_head, *list_pointer=list_head.next;

    list_pointer.value = 0; // another way without discarding list_pointer content
    list_head.next=&n1;
    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.value = 300;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it runs ok but i have done it manually the question would be "how the function of inserting a node before it's first element" will look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
struct entry {
 int value;
 struct entry *next;

};
//X struct u want to target
struct entry insertentry(struct entry *new_entry, struct entry *x){
int data;

printf("Enter a value for your new entry");
scanf("%i",&data);
new_entry->value=data;
new_entry->next=x->next;
x->next=&(*new_entry);
return *new_entry;};

int main (void)
{struct entry n1, n2, n3,n4,n5,list_head;
struct entry *list_pointer;
n1.value = 100;
list_head.next=&n1;

n4=insertentry(&n5,&list_head);
list_pointer=&n4;
n1.next = &n2;
n2.value = 200;
n2.next = &n3;
n3.value = 300;

n3.next = (struct entry *) 0; // Mark list end with null pointer
while ( list_pointer != (struct entry *) 0 ) {
printf ("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
}
printf("%i\n",n5.value);


getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, actually you need more variables if you want to insert more nodes but for that you should use an array or you allocate every node you add.